# Google Sheet API v4 "Unable to parse range" when getting table data

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to learn the Google Sheets API for PHP to read data from a sheet. I'm using https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/ to read a Google Sheet that is not published to the web. I've set up access permissions in the Google Sheets API in my Google Account. My basic connection works, using this:

```
// Connect the Google Sheets API client
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Load service key
$googleAccountKeyFilePath = __DIR__ . '/service_key.json';
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . $googleAccountKeyFilePath);

// Create new client
$client = new Google_Client();

// Set credentials
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

// Access for reading, editing, creating and deleting tables
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets');

$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

// Spreadsheet ID
$spreadsheetId = 'my_id';

$response = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetId);

// Get properties of spreadsheet
$spreadsheetProperties = $response->getProperties();

// spreadsheet name
var_dump($spreadsheetProperties->title);
```

and `var_dump` outputs

`string(4) "Test"`

But when I try

```
$range = 'Test';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
var_dump($response);
```

to dump the all cells in the sheet Test, I get the error

`Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Unable to parse range: Test", "errors": [ { "message": "Unable to parse range: Test", "domain": "global", "reason": "badRequest" } ], "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } }`

What's an example of how to dump the cell data?

Comment: The [note for range](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) is `The A1 notation or R1C1 notation of the range to retrieve values from`, so `Test` is not a valid range. Try `A1:A6` and see if that gives you anything. (Edit) https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php has a much better example

Comment: Ah, that works, thanks! Add that as an answer. BTW, does my basic connection code look OK? It's much simpler than that example you linked.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. I haven't used the Sheets API at all, just found the documentation for it.

Comment: I read some of the docs, but could only parse some of them. I was using https://pocketadmin.tech/en/version-4-of-the-google-sheets-api-in-php/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range must use A1 notation or R1C1 notation, per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get). So range should be

```
$range = 'A1:A6';
```

or

```
$range = 'A[1]:A[6]';
```

If you need to specify the tab name, that goes before the range. From [the example](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php), it would look like

```
$range = 'Class Data!A2:E';
```